# Overwrite text object and infinite loop

Tags: python, blackjack, zelle-graphics

I can't get the new total to replace the previous total, it just prints it overtop. Also if anyone could help with why my dealers cards are on an infinite loop.

Here's part of my code, it messes up once it gets to the while true statement.

```
def main():

    # card deck and shuffle it
    win = GraphWin('Blackjack', 800, 600)
    deck = CardDeck()
    deck.shuffle()

    # hit me button
    hitp = Point(650, 125)
    hitButton = Text(hitp, "Hit me")
    hitButton.draw(win)
    hitbox = Rectangle(Point(600, 100), (Point(700, 150)))
    hitbox.draw(win)

    # player's starting hand
    card = deck.dealOne()
    value, filename = cardInfo(card)
    drawCard(filename, 100, 100, win)
    playerTotal = value
    card = deck.dealOne()
    value, filename = cardInfo(card)
    drawCard(filename, 200, 100, win)
    playerTotal = playerTotal + value
    # display total
    hand_total = Text(Point(100, 200), playerTotal)
    hand_total.draw(win)


    # dealer's starting hand
    card = deck.dealOne()
    value, filename = cardInfo(card)
    drawCard(filename, 100, 300, win)
    dealerTotal = value
    # display total
    dhand_total = Text(Point(100, 400), dealerTotal)
    dhand_total.draw(win)


    while True:
        pt = win.getMouse()
        x = pt.getX()
        y = pt.getY()
        if 600 < x < 700 and 100 < y < 150:
            value, filename = cardInfo(card)
            drawCard(filename, 300, 100, win)
            playerTotal = playerTotal + value
            hand_total = Text(Point(100, 200), playerTotal)
            hand_total.draw(win)
            if playerTotal > 21:
                break
        else:
            break
    if playerTotal <= 21:
        while dealerTotal < 17:
            card = deck.dealOne()
            value, filename = cardInfo(card)
            drawCard(filename, 200, 300, win)
            dealerTotal2 = value
            dhand_total = Text(Point(100, 400), dealerTotal2)
            dhand_total.draw(win)
            if dealerTotal >= 21:
                break

    # wait for mouse click before closing window
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

It's a blackjack game that is supposed to break once the player busts or the dealer gets 17 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide enough code to run your program, I can only make untested suggestions.  Your problem seems to be this code:

```
hand_total = Text(Point(100, 200), playerTotal)
hand_total.draw(win)
```

And the matching `dhand_total` code for the dealer.  You're creating a new text object every time through the loop without removing the old one.  A quick and dirty fix might be adding the line:

```
hand_total.undraw()
hand_total = Text(Point(100, 200), playerTotal)
hand_total.draw(win)
```

But a better approach would be to replace both lines with one that changes the text of the current `Text` instance without creating a new one:

```
hand_total.setText(playerTotal)
```